# Recently/frequently used items

Tags: usability

Users are trained on our call-center software. The opening page is a list 200+ clients (buttons) from which they will pick a given client. We already have a search/filter - as soon as you start typing, the matches appear, then narrow down as you add more letters.

We want to add a Recent/Frequent section, so that their common clients are right there for them. I've read this question but want further clarification:

[When showing a list of files, is there a preference between 'Recently Used' and 'Frequently Used'?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/90858/when-showing-a-list-of-files-is-there-a-preference-between-recently-used-and?newreg=ceba78fe95954607b0c7e4405d26a633)

We are storing this using local storage.

I had started down the down of frequently used, but my boss pointed out that I have to store *every* client, and each one has to have a counter to keep track of frequency.
His suggestion is to make it just like a cache - last-used item gets moved to top. (it's *moved*, not just added, therefore it never appears twice).

Need some guidance as to which is better for our purposes, and why.

Comment: Why store every client? Just store the ID of the ones they access and increment a counter on that to get a rank for the week / month / quarter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that storing every client wouldn't be a problem at all (since it's just in the hundreds), especially if some kind of short ID was used, but you wouldn't have to store every client- just as each one was used. If I only ever picked 10 clients from the home page, I would only need to have those 10 in my client ID -> count map in my local storage.

I would offer all 4 options:

- Search for client using AJAX-style autocomplete/filtering as you mention
- Top N recently used
- Top N frequently used
- Browse, with different sort options (alphabetically, date of last contact, ... other sortable fields)